# An array is overwritten here. it's very easy, but it doesn't work for me

Tags: kotlin

/*
An array is overwritten here.
it's very easy, but it doesn't work for me.
the array should be overwritten in the second place with "yey".
in my opinion i did everything right.
It doesn't work

Please help.
*/

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        var myArray = arrayOf(42,1337,20,"Hello World ;) ")
                            
        myArray[2] = "yey" 
        println(myArray[2])
 }
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting. Otherwise it's impossible to understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of mixed types, the compiler can only guess at what type you intended, and it is picking a covariant type that doesn't allow you to change the values (`out Comparable<*>`). You need to specify an invariant type in this case so the compiler won't make the wrong decision on your behalf.

```
var myArray: Array<Any> = arrayOf(42,1337,20,"Hello World ;) ")
```

or

```
var myArray: Array<Comparable<*>> = arrayOf(42,1337,20,"Hello World ;) ")
```

In practice, it will be very rare for you to have any need of creating an Array of mixed types like this.

Comment: (In fact, in practice it's quite rare to need an array at all, as a list is more suitable for most purposes.)